# Convert timestamp (int) to time interval

Tags: r, datetime, timedelta

I have some integers (timestamps) and I want to convert them into time intervals (time deltas). How can I do that in R?

Something like this:

```
strptime(37998530.34, format="%d %H:%M")
```

This R code returns with error:

```
difftime(37998530.34, 0)
```

In Python I can use this code:

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 37998530.34)
```

And the result is:

```
datetime.timedelta(439, 68930, 340000)
439 days, 19:08:50.340000
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R you need to specify the origin for the date conversion.  Assuming your value is the number of seconds use this function:

```
as.POSIXlt(37998530.34, origin="1970-01-01")
#[1] "1971-03-16 14:08:50 EST"
```

as.POSIXlt function also has an option to specify the desired timezone (tz= )

The following code:

```
difftime(as.POSIXlt(37998530.34, origin="1970-01-01"), as.POSIXlt(0, origin="1970-01-01"), units=c('days'))
```

has the result:

```
Time difference of 439.8 days
```

Comment: Thank you! I added the final solution to your answer.